# Generating EJB stub classes on liberty

Tags: websphere-liberty

I am working on migrating application from WAS 8.5 to liberty.

There is a java standalone application which uses stub classes to communicate with the remote ejb.

The stubs were generated previously using the createStubs.bat script available on WAS 8.5

As the script is not available on liberty, how will the stubs be generated?

I read about the java rmic command but not sure if it will generate all required stubs

Let me know if there is any other way to create the stubs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Liberty has the ability to generate the stubs during runtime and not require you to generate them to put them into your application.  It depends on the version of EJBs that you are using in your application.  You can read about the details here:  https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSD28V_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.core.doc/ae/twlp_ejb_remote.html under the Stub classes section

Comment: We are using both 2.x and 3.x EJB in the application

Comment: The documentation states to use rmic for the 2.x beans, but you should be ok with the 3.x ones to not have to generate them.